# Redis as service fails with error code 87

Tags: redis

I have installed Redis-64 using the chocolately package.  When I try and install redis as a service on windows with command:

```
 redis-server.exe --service-install
```

I get the following error:

```
# HandleServiceCommands: system error caught. error code=1073, message = CreateService failed: unknown error
```

I have also tried just executing the exe on its own, but get another different error:

```
# Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone else got this error before?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error, on a Windows 7 machine. Didn't find a solution yet, sadly.

Answer (score 8):

Go to redis path and then

1) C:\Program Files\Redis>redis.windows.conf it will open file

2) Change port to 16379(higher) then run

3) C:\Program    Files\Redis>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when running the exe. *(No such file or directory)*

It worked when using a higher port in **redis.windows.conf**:

```
port 16379
```

and then run

```
c:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

What is meant by run

```
cd to c:\Program Files\Redis
```

then:

```
run redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf on command prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port to higher has solved the error for me.

Change the port in two files
redis.windows-service.conf and redis.windows.conf

And then run

```
c:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf

c:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server.exe redis.windows-service.conf
```

After run you can see below description
[image: After run you can see below description]

Answer (score 0):

For me the default port was already in use. I checked this by:

1. Pressing Windows + R
2. Typing resmon.exe
3. Going to Network > Listening Ports

There I saw that I already had a redis process running on port 6379, so I:

1. Opened Task Manager
2. Found redis-server.exe
3. Right click > End task

You can also end the process by running `redis-server --service-stop`.

Then `redis-server --service-start` worked as expected, no need to change config files.